# "as well as I" vs "as well as me"

Tags: personal-pronouns, subject-vs-object-pronouns

Should I "as well as I" or "as well as me" in the following sentence?

> John  visited the party last night **as well as I/as well as me.**

Comment: Actually, I would recommend that you do not use the "as well as" construction for that situation.  There are several other phrasings that flow much better and are more common, depending on the surrounding context.

Comment: I agree with Hellion: the best answer is **"don't use either of those, because that is not how a native speaker would say it."**  More fluent is "... **as did I** ."

Comment: John as well as I went to the party last night.  People do use t his. Sorry. But put it at the beginning not the end. It is often parenthetical: John - as well as I - went to the party last night.

Answer (score 4):

Your question forms part of the long debate over the uses of the personal pronouns **I** and **me**. The issue arises partly because in most contexts usages such as: **It is I** tend to sound archaic and formal.

For example, the majority of English speakers would probably say: **It's me at the door.** rather than **It is I at the door**.

Most confusion occurs when speakers are not aware that **I** and **we** are used as the subject of the verb and **me** and **us** as the object, whether direct or indirect.

So one hears people saying things like: **Me (or Myself) and my friend were at the party** and **This comes from my wife and I**. These are simply wrong.

Coming to your particular question: while it's correct to say:**John visited the party as well as I**, it sounds all wrong and very few native English speakers would say that.

Nearly all would say **as well as me** in the same way that they would say **It's me at the door.** The use of **I** sounds more natural if you add **did**. **He visited the party last night as well as I did.**

Things get a bit trickier in constructions such as: **It was I who gave them a lift.** You are likely to hear: **It was me who gave them a lift** but this (*me gave*) is wrong - at least until such time as popular usage makes it inevitable.

So the short answer to your question is that if you want to sound natural, prefer **me**; or add **did** after I.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96718/which-is-correct-i-or-me

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823040749/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/i-or-me)

http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/when-to-use-i-and-when-to-use-me

http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/style-and-usage/when-to-use-i-or-me-in-a-sentence.html

Answer (score 1):

This situation is actually *different* from the often discussed examples like '**than I/than me**' 
(https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461930/what-should-come-as-object-i-or-me/461932#461932) where a choice is possible to use I as the second *subject* or *me* as an *object*. If the sense is that ***both** visited that party*, it's about **subject** and there *must* be **I**:

> John as well as **I** visited the party last night.

With another word order (like in the question) you most likely need to 'refresh' the verb (as you can see, *me did* is impossible):

> John visited the party last night as well as **I did**.

If you simply use *me*,

> John visited the party last night as well as me.

the *sense will change* to '*he visited **both the party and me***' (me is an *object*).

Comment: It's a nice distinction that I should have noticed in my answer - although I suspect that it would have escaped lesser scrutiny.

Comment: I like your answer but I think "...as well as I did" is not really correct (it sounds like "he visited the party as skillfully as I did"); "...as **did I**" seems like a more fluent way to phrase it.

Comment: The Parliamentary History of England from the Earliest Period to ..., Volume 8
_The honourable gentleman who sits near me, agreed to it **as well as I did**; both of us did agree to it..._