# Is it OK to say 'as well as me'?

Tags: phrase-usage

There's a similar question to this in this [discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/177728/110852), but my question is focused on the usage of '*as well as*'.

There was someone on Facebook seemed to agree with my opinion/condition and he said **as well as me**. I sense this saying sounds awkward. I mean, he could say **me too** instead. Is it OK to use '*as well as*' that way?

The context that *Old Brixtonian* has requested:

> A: I can't open this game. What's the problem?
>
> B: **As well as me**. I hope they will fix the game.

Comment: We need to know the context. What was his whole sentence?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I'll edit a bit. Please wait a minute. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Thinking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly...**
If you had said, "I **can** open this game", he could have said, "Me too" or, even better, "So can I" or "Yes, I can too," because they are all *positive*, like "I can".

But "I **can't**" is *negative* and it needs a negative response. "Neither can I" would be perfect. Or "No, I can't either."

They need to *match*: positive to positive, negative to negative.

**Secondly...**
In "I can't open this game", **I** is the subject and **game** is the object. If your friend replies, "As well as me", **me** is the object. So it means "And you can't open **me**." That's why "Neither can I" or "No, I can't either" are better.

If someone says, "She hit him", *him* is the object. If you then say, "Me too" it means she also hit *you*. If you say, "So did I" it means you both hit him.

So. That's why I said (in my first sentence), *...or, even better, "So can I" or "Yes, I can too"*: **me** is always the *object* of the sentence.

**Finally...**
Those are the rules!! **BUT** - people *do* say, "Me too" where, grammatically, it should be "I too". If you ask children, "Who would like a sugary drink?" they will shout "Me!" It would be grammatically correct to shout "I would!", but in informal English it's a [lost cause](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lost_cause) and most adults in the UK would do the same. (Especially this week if you offered them a can of petrol!)

Comment: Thank you. Regarding your example when someone says 'She hit him', in that case, can I use 'as well as me' there? To be honest, my context I've provided above isn't that relevant since I don't remember the original context. My point is, **as well as me** is accepted or not? I mean in any contexts? Or should I say **as well as I**. Since you've known the context, my real point is asking whether that phrase is possibly used or not no matter used in whatever context.

Comment: You _could_ use "As well as me" there, but it doesn't mean "me too". It's like this: John's father: "She hit _you_, John? But you had _both_ kicked her dog." John: "She hit Richard as well as me." It means it wasn't only YOU that she hit.                              "As well as I" is old-fashioned English. "You can sing as well as I" means "We can sing equally well". Nowadays we usually add "can" at the end: "...as well as I can". "He sings as loudly as I". Nowadays we add "do" at the end: "as loudly as I do". Just remember that "I" is always the subject: never the object.

Comment: To put it simply, it depends whether _I/me_ is the subject or object. You would say "She hit me", so you say "She hit him as well as me".

Comment: @Kate Bunting: When is 'me' ever the subject, or 'I' the object?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - I meant that the OP could choose which to use depending on its grammatical function, of course!!

Comment: @user516076: About the positive/negative rule, you might find [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26239/agreement-with-so-and-neither) helpful.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: Ah - I get it!